# Implement a Swift protocol by automatically mapping method calls to keys in a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In Objective C I have previously been able to implement an automatic mechanism to allow an object with a private NSDictionary property to implement a simple protocol by automatically converting method invocations to dictionary 'valueForKey' requests, and passing these to the dictionary that has the appropriate key:value.

For example, I would have an object 'ABCArtist', which would implement the artistProtocol. This protocol has a method -(NSString*)artistName; and the 'ABCArtist' object would implement this method by returning [self.privateDictionary valueForKey:artistName];

This process relied on overriding the NSObject methods:

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation;
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector;
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector;
```

I have tried to apply the same process in Swift, however I am unable to use this as I get the compiler error:

> 'NSInvocation' is unavailable in Swift: NSInvocation and related APIs
>   not available

Is there any way that anyone has found to implement a protocol by automatically querying a dictionary for a value with the same name as the protocol method?

The use case for this is in mapping to a dictionary of JSON content returned from an API, if this automatic mapping can be accomplished, I only need to write the protocol, and forward it to the generated JSON dictionary.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? Using a dictionary as a backing store is almost certainly far more work than simply implementing properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of dynamic handling of arbitrary messages at runtime can only be done in Objective-C. For one thing, calls to pure Swift methods don't even go through the Objective-C dynamic dispatch mechanism. So it would have to be an `@objc` method, and the `forwardInvocation:` logic will have to be implemented in Objective-C.

Comment: Yeah I was ending up with the same conclusion, but thought I might as well ask, thanks for the reply!